# Difference between nested locks and simple locks

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

i am unable to figure out the difference between  omp_nest_lock_t  and omp_lock_t lck;
this code perfectly synchronizes the longtask(),  but on execution unable to figure out the difference between them;

```
  omp_nest_lock_t lck_n;          //omp_lock_t lck;
    int t_id;
    omp_init_nest_lock(&lck_n);    //omp_init_lock(&lck);
    omp_set_num_threads(6);

    #pragma omp parallel private(t_id) shared(lck_n) 
    {
    t_id = omp_get_thread_num();
    omp_set_nest_lock(&lck_n);      //omp_set_lock(&lck);
    printf("\nhi by %d\n",t_id);
    long_task();
    printf("My thread id is %d.\n", id);
   omp_unset_nest_lock(&lck_n);      //omp_unset_lock(&lck);
    }
    omp_destroy_nest_lock(&lck_n);    //omp_destroy_lock(&lck);
```

Comment: i would suggest to make the lock static so that it would check for the   locking condition and then go inside the loop. i hope it helps you out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A nested lock can be locked several times. It doesn't unlock until you have unset it as many times as the number of calls to `omp_set_nest_lock`.

A simple lock should only be `omp_set_lock` once, and unlocks on one call to `omp_unset_lock`.

The purpose of having nested locks is that you can have functions that call other functions using the same lock. E.g.

```
class object { int number; ... }
linked_list<object&> ll;
omp_nest_lock_t ll_lock;

void add_to_linked_list(object& o)
{
    omp_set_nest_lock(ll_lock);

    ll.push_back(o);

    omp_unset_nest_lock(ll_lock);
}

void increement_or_add(object& o)
{
    omp_set_nest_lock(ll_lock);
    if (ll.find(o)) 
       o.number++;
    else 
      add_to_linked_list(o);
    omp_unset_nest_lock(ll_lock);
}
```

Now, this wouldn't work if you used simple locks, because setting/unsetting the lock more than once is not allowed, and we couldn't guarantee that the "add" is done atomically - thus two threads could potentially update `ll` with the same value at once.

(The code above is written to illustrate the situation, not necessarily as "good code").